# Redshift: Query returning broken Japanese character

Tags: unicode, utf-8, amazon-redshift

My data in AWS Redshift is in Japanese. When I am selecting data row by row there is no problem. I am getting perfect characters. But when I am selecting all data from the table the query returning me some broken characters.

When my query is: select * from table_A where item_id=x;
My query returning: 日配

When my query is: select * from table_A;
My query returning the same value as  ���配

This happens only for one or two rows only. the rest are okay. If I re-order my query with order by clause instead of the previous values some new values become broken.

Normally, I upload data using the Pyspark Glue job, but I tried uploading directly using the copy command. I used both Parquet and CSV formats. But, the result is the same. Before uploading the data I confirmed that the data encoding is UTF-8. The data was imported from the Microsoft Excel file using panda read_excel and then saved in Parquet format. I also tried manually saving the data in UTF-8 and UTF-8 BOM from excel and from notepad. But, no luck.

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify if the data is not being loaded correctly or if the data is not being presented to you correctly when selecting?

Comment: The data is not presented to me correctly when I am selecting or getting a response from API. The data is loaded without any error. @BillWeiner

Comment: So while not conclusive let's go with this is a data presentation issue.  What bench are you using?  Does the issue persist if you use a different bench?

Comment: From my lambda function, I am querying using redshift-data API, language python. I am also using redshift editor. Both of these two the result is the same. The cluster is inside a separate VPC. I didn't check from other workbenches yet. @BillWeiner

Comment: Can you confirm that your python is processing multi-byte UTF-8 character encodings?  A common issue with non-ascii characters is that other programs are using different encodings than UTF-8 which Redshift uses.  This is especially true when Windows is in the mix.